# How to make a value in a database a universal variable which can be called

Tags: python, mysql, variables, global

I am trying to make a chat app which is linked with a database which stores the users username and password but i would like to call the username in multiple functions. I currently have a global variable which is called NAME_KEY and i would like to replace it with the username of which ever user is logged in.

Here is my code as it currently stands!

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, session, request, url_for, jsonify, flash, Blueprint
from .database import DataBase
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import bcrypt
import MySQLdb
from config import *

view = Blueprint("views", __name__)

# GLOBAL CONSTANTS
NAME_KEY = 'username'
MSG_LIMIT = 20

socketio = SocketIO(app)  # used for user communication


db = MySQL(app)

password = b"1234"

hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

# VIEWS
@view.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    """
    displays main login page and handles saving name in session
    :exception POST
    :return: None
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
            username = request.form.get('username')
            password = request.form.get('password').encode("utf-8")
            cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (username, password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()
            if info is not None:
                if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed):
                    session['loginsuccess'] = True
                    flash(f'You were successfully logged in as {username}.')
                    return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash("Profile doesn't exist please try again!")

    return render_template("login.html", **{"session": session})

@view.route('/new/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_user():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "one" in request.form and "two" in request.form and "three" in request.form:
            username = request.form['one']
            email = request.form['two']
            password = request.form['three']
            cur = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO login.logininfo(name, password, email)VALUES(%s, %s, %s)",
                        (username, password, email))
            db.connection.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("register.html")

@view.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """
    logs the user out by popping username from session
    :return: None
    """
    session.pop(NAME_KEY, None)
    flash("0You were logged out.")
    return redirect(url_for("views.login"))

@view.route("/")
@view.route("/home")
def home():
    """
    displays home page if logged in
    :return: None
    """
    if NAME_KEY not in session:
        return redirect(url_for("views.login"))

    return render_template("index.html", **{"session": session})

@view.route("/history")
def history():
    if NAME_KEY not in session:
        flash("0Please login before viewing message history")
        return redirect(url_for("views.login"))

    json_messages = get_history(session[NAME_KEY])
    print(json_messages)
    return render_template("history.html", **{"history": json_messages})

@view.route("/get_name")
def get_name():
    """
    :return: a json object storing name of logged in user
    """
    data = {"name": ""}
    if NAME_KEY in session:
        data = {"name": session[NAME_KEY]}
    return jsonify(data)

@view.route("/get_messages")
def get_messages():
    """
    :return: all messages stored in database
    """
    db = DataBase()
    msgs = db.get_all_messages(MSG_LIMIT)
    messages = remove_seconds_from_messages(msgs)

    return jsonify(messages)

@view.route("/get_history")
def get_history(name):
    """
    :param name: str
    :return: all messages by name of user
    """
    db = DataBase()
    msgs = db.get_messages_by_name(name)
    messages = remove_seconds_from_messages(msgs)

    return messages
```

Currently this line of code is throwing an error
'cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)'

The error is as follows
"KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'"

I also have no idea how to go about replacing the global variable NAME_KEY with one that takes which ever user is signed up and stored in my database.

I also have a config file which is as follows

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path  # python3 only
import os
from flask import Flask

# set path to env file
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

app = Flask(__name__)

class Config:
    """Set Flask configuration vars from .env file."""

    # Load in environment variables
    TESTING = os.getenv('TESTING')
    FLASK_DEBUG = os.getenv('FLASK_DEBUG')
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
    SERVER = os.getenv('SERVER')

    app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "login@localhost"
    app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
    app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "pleasehelp"
    app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "login"
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 46, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\testApp\testApp\application\views.py", line 40, in login
    cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 94, in connection
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 43, in connect
    if current_app.config['MYSQL_HOST']:
KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the username.

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: have you tried only with localhost?

Comment: `MYSQL_HOST` should just be `localhost`, or a domain, or an IP. the `MYSQL_USER` is the authenticating user.

Comment: @danblack i have tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 but neither work

Comment: @Barmar I have added all the errors on at the bottom

Comment: That's unreadable with the error messages mixed into the code. Just paste the traceback the way it was in the terminal.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry is that better?